# Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object GeolocationPositionError]

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, bluebird, navigator

While trying to get the geolocation from the user's browser, if the user has denied permission or blocked the browser from sharing the location we get a console warning from Bluebird that says: `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object GeolocationPositionError]`.

However when we catch and log the error, we get the error message: `User denied geolocation prompt` which comes from the Geolocation API's [GeolocationPositionError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationPositionError). I imagine the same warning would be logged for the other two cases in which the GeolocationPositionError would be returned (an internal position error or a timeout).

So why are we getting that console warning and how do we handle it properly?

Here is the code that handles the browser navigator & geolocation:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

function getUserLocation() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    } else {
      // Browser does not support geolocation at all
      reject(new Error('Geolocation is unsupported'));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading Bluebird's documentation on its warning message: ["Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error"](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error), I found that the problem was that the [GeolocationPositionError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationPositionError) is not a Javascript `Error` instance which is explicitly what Bluebird is expecting. So instead, customizing the `reject()` callback to explicitly cast the GeolocationPositionError as an `Error` resolved the console warning and error handling, for any case of the GeolocationPositionError.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

export function getUserLocation() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        resolve,
        (geolocationPositionError) => { // reject
          // Note: must explicitly cast the `GeolocationPositionError` as an Error instance since bluebird explicitly expects a javascript Error object
          // see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error
          // and `GeolocationPositionError` is not an Error instance, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationPositionError
          return reject(new Error(geolocationPositionError));
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Browser does not support geolocation at all
      reject(new Error('Geolocation is unsupported'));
    }
  });
```